# How to find number of paired matched data?

Tags: r

I want to test how many repeated data there are in a list of dataset. say i have something like

```
c(1,3,5,6,3,2,4,6,4,3,2,1,2)
```

How can I get 9 which is the number of paired matched data in this list? (two 1, three 2, three 3, two 4, two 6. so 7 pairs but 9 times that they match when you run a loop from left to right) I tried to use intersect, but it doesn't seem to return the right result I want.

> so i misunderstood it and corrected above

Comment: Not sure what you mean by  `number of paired matched data`

Comment: @jdharrison like the number of times that a number would coincide the same number. Let's say there are five 3's, then it would coincide itself for 10 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`choose` gives you the number of combinations:

```
x <- c(1,3,5,6,3,2,4,6,4,3,2,1,2)
y <- table(x)

sum(choose(y, 2))
#[1] 9
```